# How to fix the muti-threading issue which i am facing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a situation where i have to call two different methods to run in parallel. I am using Python threading module to achieve this. But, instead of two methods running in parallel, they are running sequentially. Can someone please guide me in what is the wrong in my code?

This is for Python 3.5, using threading module and have a class with two different methods which has to be run in parallel.

```py
## This is in template.py
from threading import Thread
import time
class createTemplate:
    def __init__(self,PARAM1):
        self.PARAM1=PARAM1

    def method1(self):
        print("Method1-START")
        time.sleep(120)
        print("Method1-END")

    def method2(self):
        print("Method2-START")
        time.sleep(120)
        print("Method2-END")

    def final_method(self):
        if self.PARAM1=="1":
           m1=Thread(target=self.method1)
           m1.run()

        if self.PARAM1=="1":
           m2=Thread(target=self.method2)
           m2.run()

## This is in createTemplate.py
from template import createTemplate

template = createTemplate("1")
template.final_method()
```

### Actual Output:

> Method1-START
>   Method1-END
>   Method2-START
>   Method2-END

### Expected Output:

> Method1-START
>   Method2-START
>   Method1-END
>   Method2-END

Answer (score 1):

instead of `.run()` you should call `.start()`

`Thread.run()` will run the code in the context of the current thread, but `Thread.start()` will actually spawn a new thread and run the code on it in parallel to existing threads.

try this:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time
class createTemplate:
    def __init__(self,PARAM1):
        self.PARAM1=PARAM1

    def method1(self, arg):
        print("Method1-START",arg)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Method1-END",arg)

    def method2(self,arg):
        print("Method2-START",arg)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Method2-END",arg)

    def final_method(self):
        if self.PARAM1=="1":
           m1=Thread(target=self.method1, args=("A", )) # <- this is a tuple of size 1
           m1.start()

        if self.PARAM1=="1":
           m2=Thread(target=self.method2, args=("B", )) # <- this is a tuple of size 1
           m2.start()
```

Comment: Hi @Adam.Er8, Thanks for pointing that out. That worked as per my expectation. But, if i pass some input parameters to the methods, it again runs sequentially. Is it not allowed to pass params?
Ex:-
m1=Thread(target=self.method1("A"))
m2=Thread(target=self.method2("B"))

def method1(self,PARAM2):
def method2(self,PARAM2):

Comment: `target` should always be a function. what you just did is call the function when creating the threads, passing the return value as a target. you need to use the `args` param. I edited my answer with example code